# How to Identify the different format types of data in a excel column

Tags: excel

I have close to one million data in a excel column. I need to identify the formats of all data and count how many data falls under each format.

For example:

[image: Example]

- Data with 10 numeric digits are to be considered as one format and
  count number of times it has repeated.
- Data with 3 numeric ditigs
  are to be considered as one format and count number of times it has
  repeated.
- And continue finding the format of data and count it.

  Could anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited it. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach:

1. Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) to enable regex matching as an in-cell formula.
2. Manually cast an eye over the data and come up with a regex that will match a good number of your values. In a new column, set this regex up as a filter condition. Filter those values out of your view.
3. Repeat step 2 until you've got a set of regexes that covers every format of data in your worksheet.

Comment: I will try and get back :) Thanks